# How to auto login in react native by redux

Tags: react-native, react-redux

Hi everyone I'm trying to get an auto-login on the app start system in my react-native app.
I'm trying to get data from AsyncStorage and dispatch a login function that stores authToken in redux state inside a useEffect function but useEffect is re-rendering and I'm stuck on my screen.

**My code**

```
 const tryLogin = async () => {

    const authToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('authToken')
    const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
    const introComplete = await AsyncStorage.getItem('intro')
 

    await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 2000))
   
    if (introComplete) {
      console.log('1')

      if (authToken) {
        console.log(2)

         login({login: true, authToken, user: JSON.parse(user || '{}')})
         
          return navigation.replace(RoutesName?.Home)
           
      } else {
        console.log(3)

        navigation.replace(RoutesName?.Home)
      }
    } else {
      console.log(4)

      navigation.replace(RoutesName?.Intro)
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('intro', 'true')
    }
  }


    React.useEffect(() => {
      tryLogin()
    }, [])
```

**Navigation flow**

```
  const SplashScreen = () => {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name={RoutesName.Splash} options={noHeaderOption}>
          {(props: any) => <Layout router={Routes.Splash} {...props} />}
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen name={RoutesName.Intro} options={noHeaderOption}>
          {(props: any) => <Layout router={Routes.Intro} {...props} />}
        </Stack.Screen>
        {auth?.login ? (
          <Stack.Screen
            name={RoutesName.Home}
            options={noHeaderOption}
            component={Home}
          />
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Auth} options={noHeaderOption} />
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    )
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <SplashScreen />
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue I'm really going mad about this.

Comment: Use `redux-persist`.

Comment: ok I'll that one

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: yes and this is the best thing to do that..